# How to display store names php?

Tags: php

I would like to know how all store names are displayed in "http://www.mytokri.com/all-stores/" the given link. Is there any API or Tool or Software used here?

Comment: Get HTML with `file_get_contents()`, then parse it (with libraries already included in PHP like e.g. SimpleXML) and get what you want from it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? I don't get what you'd like to know.

Comment: What have you tried by far and what challenge are you facing? Any error(s)?

Comment: I would like to get all the shopping site names with URL as given in the mentioned link "http://www.mytokri.com/all-stores/" Kindly visit the website.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for you using `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` can be the following:

You can download library from [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
<?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $url = "http://www.mytokri.com/all-stores/";    
    $html = file_get_html($url); // you don't need to use curl
    $yourDesiredContent = $html->find('div.store-listing', 0)->plaintext;
    print_r($yourDesiredContent); 
?>
```

Comment: Actually i have given that URL for sample purpose. I need the same kind of page to be displayed in my website. It is not possible to store all those names in Database.How to get all all store names from web? is there any API or tool available to get all those names. Kindly let me know

Comment: @sridevi : you can use the above code and pass the url from where you want to scrap the data. it's just  an example output of your query. you  can also use `curl` to get the data from API and display on your web page.